# Can I render a WPF window with buttons on a touch sensitive screen and read the input? Suggestions?

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I want to create a WPF window that will display on a touch sensitive screen and the window contains 80 buttons. I want my WPF app to recognize tabs on specific buttons. Do I need any specific API to do that or how will the tabs on the touch sensitive screen be transmitted to my WPF app?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Touch is same like mouse gestures. Why do you need a separate API for that? Mouse left button click will obviously be handled when a touch is received on the touch sensitive screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 and its higher versions have the ability to receive input from multiple touch-sensitive devices. WPF applications can also handle touch input as other input, such as the mouse or keyboard, by raising events when a touch occurs.

WPF exposes two types of events when a touch occurs − touch events and manipulation events. Touch events provide raw data about each finger on a touchscreen and its movement. Manipulation events interpret the input as certain actions. Both types of events are discussed in this section.

WPF enables applications to respond to touch. For example, you can interact with an application by using one or more fingers on a touch-sensitive device, such as a touchscreen This walkthrough creates an application that enables the user to move, resize, or rotate a single object by using touch.

Source MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649090.aspx

Also read this codeproject article - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692286/WPF-and-multi-touch

Comment: I too referred the same while developing a prototype application using multi touch gestures.

Answer (score 1):

WPF applications work on the touch screen without any needs for modifications. Of course you can add support for gestures like pinch-zooming etc. but tapping on buttons works out of the box. For the WPF application it doesn't matter if user is tapping with the finger or clicking with the mouse.